# How to change the size of row cells in UItableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

I am new to iPhone app development and i am currently doing a sample table view project. How do i change the size of row cells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of [`UITableViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (Dynamic) 
    {
        //calculate dynamic height and return from here;
        return dynamicheight;
    }
    else
        return fixedheight; //Return fixed height from here e.g. 40
}
```

Comment: Pls post your code as new question what have you tried and what you are trying to achieve ? Definitely will look into that and help you.

Answer (score 5):

Use this for height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            return 10;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 245;
            break;

        case 2:
            return 60;
            break;

        case 3:
            return 120;
            break;

        case 4:
            return 60;
            break;

        case 5:
            return 76;
            break;

        case 6:
            return 60;
            break;

        case 7:
            return 120;
            break;

        case 8:
            return 60;
            break;

        case 9:
            return 76;
            break;

        case 10:
            return 60;
            break;

        case 11:
            return 76;
            break;

        case 12:
            return 60;
            break;

        case 13:
            return 76;
            break;

        default:
            return 44;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good programming practice. What if there are 100 rows with different size ? will you write that much switch cases ?